# Qt: The relation between Worker thread and GUI Events

Tags: c++, qt

I have an ordinary GUI Thread (Main Window) and want to attach a Worker thread to it. The Worker thread will be instantiated, moved to its own thread and then fired away to run on its own independently, running a messaging routine (non-blocking).

This is where the worker is created:

```
void MainWindow::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    Worker* workwork;
    workwork= new Worker();

    connect(workwork,SIGNAL(invokeTestResultsUpdate(int,quint8)),
                      this,SLOT(updateTestResults(int,quint8)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(emitInit()),workwork,SLOT(init()));

    workwork->startBC();
}
```

This is where the Worker starts:

```
void Worker::startBC()
{
    t1553 = new QThread();    
    this->moveToThread(t1553);
    connect(t1553,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(run1553Process()));
    t1553->start();
}
```

I have two problems here, regarding the event queue of the new thread:

The first and minor problem is that, while I can receive the signals from the Worker thread (namely: `invokeTestResultsUpdate`), I cannot invoke the `init` method by emitting the `emitInit` signal from `MainWindow`. It just doesn't fire unless I call it directly or connect it via `Qt::DirectConnection` . Why is this happening? Because I have to start the Worker thread's own messaging loop explicitly? Or some other thing I'm not aware of? (I really fail to wrap my head around the concept of Thread/Event Loop/Signal Slot mechanism and the relation between each other even though I try. I welcome any fresh perspective here too.)

The second and more obscure problem is: `run1553process` method does some ***heavy*** work. By heavy work, I mean a very high rate of data. There is a loop running, and I try to receive the data flowing from a device (real-time) as soon as it lands in the buffer, using mostly `extern` API functions. Then throw the mentioned `invokeTestResultsUpdate` signal towards the GUI each time it receives a message, updating the message number box. It's nothing more than that.

The thing I'm experiencing is weird; normally the messaging routine is mostly unhindered but when I resize the main window, move it, or hide/show the window, the Worker thread skips many messages. And the resizing action is really slow (not responds very fast). It's really giving me a cancer.

(Note: I have tried subclassing QThread before, it did not mitigate the problem.)

I've been reading all the "Thread Affinity" topics and tried to apply them but it still behaves like it is *somehow* interrupted by the GUI thread's events at some point. I can understand MainWindow's troubles since there are many messages at the queue to be executed (both the invoked slots and the GUI events). But I cannot see as to why a background thread is affected by the GUI events. I really need to have an extremely robust and unhindered message routine running seperately behind, firing and forgetting the signals and not giving a damn about anything.

I'm really desperate for any help right now, so any bit of information is useful for me. Please do not hesitate to throw ideas.

Comment: Why is someone giving my question (-) vote? I would appreciate any comment about what is wrong with it. Really.

Comment: Is your worker thread running an event loop? You might need one to receive queued signals from other threads. I can recommend this read for further information: https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects

Comment: I think my main problem is that I don't know how to run a separate event loop within a thread.

Comment: If you subclass `QThread` directely you can just call `QThread::exec()`in your `QThread::run` method to start the event loop. but for greater detail better read the wiki link I provided inthe last comment. :)

Comment: Thank you, @xander . That helps.

Comment: @commenters above. `t1553->start();` starts the event loop. Subclassing QThread does often more damage that good.

Comment: Side note, good reference for QThread: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: Does `run1553Process` block the event loop? i.e. is it a long synchronous operation?

Comment: @IlBeldus , as I have stated, it is not a blocking operation, on the contrary, it's a very fast, repeating loop with no shared variables and has Normal priority (I haven't mingled with `QThread` priorities, I know that's a dark path.)

Comment: By the way, I cannot receive the signals fired from the `MainWindow` even after starting the Worker thread. That's why I'm confused. Normally, I would subclass `QThread` and all my slots would be triggered after calling `start()`. This `moveToThread` approach is alien to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: call `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` periodiacally inside `run1553process`.

Full explanation:
Signals from the main thread are put in a queue and executed once the event loop in the second thread takes control. In your implementation you call `run1553Process` as soon as the thread starts. the control will not go back to the event loop until the end of that function or `QCoreApplication::processEvents` is manually invoked so signals will just sit there waiting for the event loop to pick them up.

P.S. 
you are leaking both the worker and the thread in the code above

P.P.S. 
Data streams from devices normally provide an asynchronous API instead of you having to poll them indefinetly

Comment: @P.P.S : That's right, I have the option to handle the messages via IRQ, but that actually gave me even more cancer after realizing that I'm missing even more messages while trying to make the interrupts play nice with the other threads.
This endeavor gave me a nice phobia of of skipped messages.

Comment: That is normally just a problem of the reader not a limit of the sender API. I'd ask how you are reading the messages but it would be OT

Comment: I'm reading MIL-STD-1553 messages from a PCIe card. My main headache circulates around this "cannot receive at the producer's rate" problem. And that's probably caused by my lack of Qt's event system and poor coordination of threads. Otherwise the system I'm working with is accurate at the microseconds level, there should not be any messages missed. I wonder if it has anything to do with the inadequacy of my test PC's processing power?

Comment: By the way, I tried your solution (adding `processEvents` into the loop at some point) and it definitely reduced the "message skipping" problem to some point. But there is still some lag left. I'm wondering, if there was a way to separate these two thread's event loops completely, maybe that would work? I mean, is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

The crucial mistake was connecting the QThread's built in `start()` signal to `run1553Process()` slot. I had thought of this as replacing `run()` with this method, and expected everything to be fine. But this caused the actual `run()` method to get blocked, therefore preventing the event loop to start.

As stated in qthread.cpp:

```
void QThread::run()
{
    (void) exec();
}
```

To fix this, I didn't touch the original `start()` signal, instead connected another signal to my `run1553Process()` independently. First started the thread ordinarily, allowed the event loop to start, then fired my other signals. That did it, now my Worker can receive all the messages.

I think now I understand the relation between threads and events better.

By the way, this solution did not take care of the message skipping problem entirely, but I feel that's caused by another factor (like my message reading implementation).

Thanks everyone for the ideas. I hope the solution helps some other poor guy like me.